# Task WhenAll usage

Tags: c#

I have a bunch of tasks defined as:

```
Task t1 = new Task( () => { /* Do Something */ } );
Task t2 = new Task( () => { /* Do Something */ } );
Task t3 = new Task( () => { /* Do Something */ } );
Task t4 = new Task( () => { /* Do Something */ } );

List<Task> allTasks = new List<Task>();
allTasks.Add(t1);
allTasks.Add(t2); etc.
```

And then finally:

```
Task.WhenAll(allTasks).ContinueWith((t) =>
{
    MyBlockingCollection.CompleteAdding();
});

foreach (Task t in allTasks)
{
    t.Start();
}
```

My questions regarding the above code:

Is this the correct way to make use of Tasks?

Does `Task.WhenAll()` start the tasks by itself or do we have to explicitly start them. If so, do we FIRST start and then do `Task.WhenALL()`?

And I need to do exception handling for these tasks as well, Could you please suggest the proper way to handle exceptions within tasks, Ideally I want the task to write out some diagnostics information to a text document if an exception happens.

I'm kind of new to the Tasks world, thanks for your help!

Comment: It seems like your questions about when tasks start can be answered by simply running your code.

Comment: regarding exception handling, Though I am not much sure but it does have `State` property set `Faulted` in case of exception occured while processing task.

Comment: If you're new to Tasks, then I would strongly recommend you to read one of the (if not _the_) best article about the subject: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx. It's written by [@Stephen Cleary](http://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Task.WhenAll() start the tasks by itself or do we have to
>   explicitly start them. If so, do we FIRST start and then do
>   Task.WhenAll()?

You need to start every task individually first, after *wait* for them.

> And I need to do exception handling for these tasks as well,..

Every task is independent execution unit, so exception handling happens inside its scope. That means that what you can do is to return an exception from the task as a *result*. Main thread will read a *result* and behave appropriately.

Comment: If I have wrapped `Task.WhenAll()` in try catch and if task throws exception would this try catch block catch the exception?

Comment: @Tigran that is false. You have several options, the best (imo) is to create multiple code paths within a single continuation. Another is to create a continuation specifically to handle faults. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcontinuationoptions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @JenishRabadiya: That's right. In case of  `Wait()`, `WaitAll()` you will recieve `AggregatedException` type from all tasks that raised an exception, *unhandled*, or *rethrown* from inside of them.

Answer (score 1):

These `Task` instances will not run if you simply call the constructor. As the Tasks have not been started, `WhenAll` will never return and you will **deadlock**.

Use `System.Threading.Task.Run` instead.

```
Task t1 = Task.Run(() => { /* Do Something */ });
Task t2 = Task.Run(() => { /* Do Something */ });
...
```

Remove the loop in which you start the tasks.

> **Task.Run Method (Action) .NET Framework 4.5**
>
> Queues the specified work to run on the ThreadPool and returns a task
>   handle for that work.
>
> [From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Further reading here: [Task Parallelism (Task Parallel Library)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Regarding exception handling, you can use the `Task` parameter to access all results, even exceptions, from within the continuation:

```
Task.WhenAll(allTasks).ContinueWith((t) =>
{
    if(t.RanToCompletion)
    {
        MyBlockingCollection.CompleteAdding();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t.Exception);
    }
});
```

More on that here: [Exception Handling (Task Parallel Library)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)